# How to determine Endianess of a file

Tags: fortran, endianness

I am having a hard time making sure if the files I am using are little Endian or Big Endian. I s there any fortran code which I can run over a file to determine its Endianess?

Thank you,

Pradeep

Comment: What is in the file?  Unless you know the value of one number you are going to struggle to know which is which

Comment: These are numeric data files containing values for double-precision arrays in the binary format. These files were written on different machines using fortran.

Comment: Cannot you just read the first could in and see what values you get. I suspect switching endian-ness may show you which is which.

Comment: There is nothing like `binary format` in Fortran. You must specify exactly what type of data you have and you must know the values you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the file with a hexeditor. Most hexeditors allow you to switch the interpretation of the bits between big and little endian.   You will have to have some idea of what values to expect.  Interpreted with the wrong endianess, the values will probably be implausible.   If the files were written as Fortran sequential files, typically each record will begin and end with an integer specifying the length of the record.  This might also help you deduce the endianess of the file.

Or, as Rob said, just try reading the file.   If it doesn't work, try the other endian.